# Are DigitalOcean Droplets Created With Snapshots Connected?

Tags: digital-ocean

I am becoming familiar with DigitalOcean and deployments and practicing horizontally scaling our application. I created a small droplet and set it up to run our app, and then took a snapshot of it and created two more droplets from that snapshot. When I deployed a new version of my app to the first droplet, the one I created a snapshot from, the other two received the same code, without me scp-ing files to them. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is "no."

My issue was with nginx configuration - I forgot to change the config files for the new servers and was proxying requests to the old one, thereby returning responses from only one server.

Comment: mildly amusing mistake,

Answer (score 0):

A DigitalOcean snapshot is a copy of the image file of your droplet at the time the snapshot was made. Essentially it is an exact copy of your droplet.

What this means is it has all the same coding for your application. So if anything was specific to the original droplet (IP for example) you might run into some issues. So if the duplicates had proxy coding that the new application is no longer using, it is likely to run into such issues.